# SharePoint 2010 Backup

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, backup, restore

All,

I am confused as to why this happens. I am trying to use the Backup-Spsite to backup the site collection. If the size of the site is 5 GB, it just goes beyond 13GB and still going. Why does this happen? Actual size of the site collection in central admin for the site collection shows 5GB. Would export of the site collection help?

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their could be different reason for this:

- recalculate the storage of site collection using this script

  $Site = Get-SPSite -identity "Site collection url"
  $Site.RecalculateStorageUsed()
- Also check if the Audit log is enabled on your site collection, if yes than check the audit logging data that may cause this issue as well.
- check the 2nd stage recycebin, if it contains data that can contribute in it.